# Which flow should I use when I have javascript clients and I want to login automatically without user consent?

Tags: identityserver3

I have an intranet application which I want to simply authenticate the users by their network ids. The users are considered trusted and I want to login the users without their interactions. In this case, which flow should I use?

I made it work with resource owner flow but I think this approach is not good enough. If I use  Implicit Flow or Authorization Code Flow, can I achieve the goal that the users do not need involved in the login process? Which means the users do not need to consent to the authentication requests?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consent is just a client setting (`RequireConsent`). But it sounds like you also want something like Windows integrated authentication.

This makes me wonder if you need an extra token service at all - since you already have one (called Windows domain controller).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is it possible to return authorize token directly to javascript client without client interaction? In my case, I can sent the networkId of the client to the identity server so that do not require user enter username/password.